# Material-Design-Lite auto full screen on browser scroll

Tags: material-design-lite

I have created a simple page with "mdl-layout__header" and other components .Unlike other web pages like google search, nytimes.com etc the browser address bar does not auto show/hide when user scrolls up/down. This could be easily seen in getmdl.io templates too.

Open following links in 2 tabs and try scrolling down

http://www.getmdl.io/templates/blog/index.html

http://www.nytimes.com/

(I'm testing on latest Chrome,Firefox,Opera in Android 5.1.1 mobile phone)

Answer (score 0):

If you searched the issue tracker on Github for the project, you would have found the [existing issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1072) about just this and why it exists.